# Passing multiple filter options

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to list my compute disks based on zone and name criteria.

However, the following command:

```
▶ gcloud compute disks list --filter="zone=europe-west4-a AND name=redash-postgres-data"
WARNING: --filter : operator evaluation is changing for consistency across Google APIs.  zone=europe-west4-a currently does not match but will match in the near future.  Run `gcloud topic filters` for details.
Listed 0 items.
```

**a**) does not return any results despite the fact that there **IS** such a disk

```
▶ gcloud compute disks list
NAME                                                LOCATION        LOCATION_SCOPE  SIZE_GB  TYPE         STATUS
redash-postgres-data                                us-east4-b      zone            50       pd-standard  READY
gke-redash-test-cluster-redash-pool1-4db01a9f-1986  europe-west4-a  zone            100      pd-standard  READY
gke-redash-test-cluster-redash-pool1-4db01a9f-t34m  europe-west4-a  zone            100      pd-standard  READY
redash-postgres-data                                europe-west4-a  zone            60       pd-standard  READY
```

**b**) how should we formulate the query so that we are future proof according to the above warning? the example I am using is from the help return by running `gcloud topic filters` as suggested by the above warning message

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT**: The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/list#--zones) that Kolban@ linked actually also mentions an alternative syntax that match a simple pattern and allows to use the short zone name:

```
--filter="zone:( us-east4-a )"
```

so your gcloud command can actually look like this:

```
gcloud compute disks list --filter="zone:( us-east4-a) AND name=redash-postgres-data"
```

---

When inspecting a disk resource via `gcloud compute disks describe disk_name`, you'll see that, next to the other info, the zone is described like a fully qualified URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_NAME/zones/us-east4-a
```

Filtering the `list` command with this full URL will work:

```
gcloud compute disks list --filter="zone=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_NAME/zones/us-east4-a AND name=redash-postgres-data"
```

Comment: Good answer ... but kind of yukky ... as the OP said, if we look here ... https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/list#--zones there is no mention of a full URL but instead shows just the zone name.